# Android Studio UPLOAD_ASSISTANT_DEVICE_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Getting this error in my logcat

> E/Bg Task Executor Impl: EXCLUSIVE background task UPLOAD_ASSISTANT_DEVICE_SETTINGS failed. Crashing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try cleaning your android project and try building again after?

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Try to Invalidate and Restart your Android Studio